# How to deploy clickonce application (Web publish) using MSBuild command line utility

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, continuous-deployment

I would like to publish my WPF application (Click once deployment) into IIS using MSBuild command line utility. I could able to publish in to file system but web publish is not working

Any suggestions would be appreciated